# verify payment in mastercard payment gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, mastercard

I have implemented MPGS in my webiste. I followed this link for the integration.https://network.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html. Everything seems to be working. After successful transaction, I am redirected to receipt.php file. I would like to verify whether the payment was successful.If possible,how can I achieve?Should I need to create a cron job or something in PHP to check if it was successful or not

```
<script src="https://network.gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/51/checkout.js"
            data-error="<?php echo $_SESSION['home_url'].'/errorpage';?>"
            data-cancel="<?php echo $_SESSION['home_url'].'/cancelpage';?>"
            data-complete="<?php echo $_SESSION['home_url'].'/receipt';?>"
            data-timeout="<?php echo $_SESSION['home_url'].'/timeout';?>"
            >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gateway sends the result of the payment in a `resultIndicator` parameter, which is either:

- appended to the URL (`interaction.returnUrl`) used for returning the payer to your shop site, OR
- provided as an input parameter to the function provided in the complete callback or appended to the URL provided in the complete callback.

You can determine the success of the payment by comparing the `resultIndicator` and the `successIndicator` parameters. A match indicates that the payment has been successful.

Comment: If am paying high amount, I need to double check if payment is successful @Zahed

Comment: It's not needed since comparing `successIndicator` is enough.